# R: Create new column based on first and last values per ID

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a longitudinal dataframe consisting of multiple IDs and multiple observations (CONC) per ID. Depending on the number of occasions (in my case administration of a drug, OCC column) the observations are flagged with each new dose (ADMIN). I would like to create a new column (OCC1) which should display the first and the last occasion per ID. OCC1 = 1 should be the respective first occasion, OCC1=2 should be the respective last occasion. All other occasions in between can be coded as zeros.

Example dataframe:

```
ID TIME ADMIN CONC OCC 
1  0    10    0    1
1  1    0     1000 1
1  8    0     560  1
1  12   0     203  1
1  24   10    56   2
1  32   0     674  2
1  36   0     457  2
2  0    20    0    1
2  12   0     144  1
2  24   20    32   2
2  36   0     97   2
2  48   20    199  3
2  60   0     120  3
```

Desired dataframe:

```
ID TIME ADMIN CONC OCC OCC1 
1  0    10    0    1   1
1  1    0     1000 1   1
1  8    0     560  1   1
1  12   0     203  1   1
1  24   10    56   2   2
1  32   0     674  2   2
1  36   0     457  2   2
2  0    20    0    1   1
2  12   0     144  1   1
2  24   20    32   2   0
2  36   0     97   2   0
2  48   20    199  3   2
2  60   0     120  3   2
```

I know that I could start with `group_by` from `dplyr` and the `first` and `last` functions would return the respective first and last values. `ifelse` would be used for assigning the desired OCC1 values and with `mutate` I could create the OCC1 column in the first place. But I could not manage to combine both first and last values into one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`case_match()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_match.html) to check when OCC matches the first and last instance of OCC, grouped by ID:

```
dplyr::mutate(df, OCC1 = dplyr::case_match(OCC,
                            dplyr::first(OCC) ~ 1,
                            dplyr::last(OCC) ~ 2,
                            .default = 0), .by = ID)
```

Notes:

- If you haven't loaded [plyr](/questions/tagged/plyr) in your environment, you can remove all of the `dplyr::`s and just have `library(dplyr)` at the beginning.
- You could alternatively use [`case_when()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html), or nested `ifelse()`s, but `case_match()` is the most concise/well-suited function to this.